# Error Trying include PrestaShopWebService in Controller

Tags: symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am trying include web service library for prestashop in a controller, but when i try include this class, i get the next error:

```
Attempted to load class "PrestaShopWebService2" from namespace "AppBundle\Services".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Prestashop v1.5.6

PrestaShopWebService2:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;
class PrestaShopWebService2
{//code}
```

DefaultController:

```
use AppBundle\Services\PrestaShopWebService2;
public function indexAction()
    {
        //code
        $persta2 = new PrestaShopWebService2("MyURL","mykey", false);
        //code
    }
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Which version of Prestashop are you using?

Comment: Prestashop v 1.5.6